# Windows authentication failing when connecting to sql server using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication

I have SQL server on a machine under the domain DOM005 and I am trying to connect to it using JDBC driver from my local machine that is in another domain. I am using windows authentication for the connection through domain administrator account.

I cannot use "integratedSecurity=true" in my connection URL since both machines are in different domain. Hence I use "authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated" but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DOM005\administrator'. ClientConnectionId:84224bcd-d2f1-4386-aadf-397c1ef3eadf
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:251)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:81)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2360)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2346)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1404)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1068)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:904)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:451)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at TestJDBCsqlServer.main(TestJDBCsqlServer.java:23)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestJDBCsqlServer {

    private static final String SQLSERVER_URL_NTLM = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.20.13.4:1433;databaseName=DB1;authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean isNTLM = true;

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        if(isNTLM){
            try{
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLSERVER_URL_NTLM, "DOM005\\administrator", "abc");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery("select 1");
                System.out.println("NTLM connection is successful");
                set.next();
                System.out.println(set.getString(1));
            }finally{
                if(stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Comment: As far as I know, in the SQL Server JDBC driver username and password authentication is only used for SQL users, not for Windows users. If you want to authenticate with a Windows user, you should use the integrated security option (Active Directory or Kerberos authentication).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am trying to use Active Directory authentication here but seems to fail.

Comment: And I say, that - as far as I know - you cannot use Active Directory authentication this way (with a username and password) with the SQL Server JDBC driver, you need to use integrated security.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried that only first. But it works only if my machine is in same domain as the sql server machine. That will not be the case always.